# mysql query with condition to query one record

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way I check if the record exist in mysql?

```
Select name FROM test as p 
Where (category = 'cat'
OR category = 'dog')
```

What I want to achieve is query name from test table, if category is cat. If there is no record from this query, then query where category is dog.

If category cat is available, don't query category dog.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is actually a good newbie question - even if the answer is "you can't do that"

Comment: Can you add the data from the table with 4 or 5 rows?

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use two queries: one for cats and one for dogs where no cats exist. Use `UNION ALL` to get both query results in one.

```
select name from test where category = 'cat'
union all
select name from test where category = 'dog'
where not exists (select * from test where category = 'cat');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some left join, it's quite expensive but it'll work :

```
Select p.name FROM test as p 
LEFT JOIN test pCat ON pCat.id = p.id and pCat.category = 'cat'
LEFT JOIN test pDog ON pDog .id = p.id and pDog .category = 'dog'
WHERE other conditions
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns names of cats if rows with category = "cat" exists. Otherwise it returns names of dogs.

```
SELECT IF(
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test WHERE category ="cat"), 
(SELECT `name` FROM test WHERE category ="cat"), 
(SELECT `name` FROM test WHERE category ="dog")
) FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplish using IF condition and inner query in mysql

```
select name, cat from test 
where cat in (select IF(t.c1>0,'cat','dog') as cat from 
(select count(cat) as c1 from test where cat='cat') t)
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake I'm showing how to do this in standard SQL. This is not available in MySQL as yet, but may be in a future version.

```
select name
from test
where category in ('cat', 'dog')
order by category
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

You see we order by category and then take the first row (`fetch first 1 row` - a cat row if any, a dog row elsewise) and all rows of the same category (`with ties`).

MySQL has a `LIMIT` clause (instead of `FETCH FIRST n ROWS`), but this has no ties clause, so it's of no use here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach in MySQL:

```
select name
from test
where category in 
(
  select min(category)
  from test
  where category in ('cat', 'dog')
);
```